# How to use compiled source GraalVM to run a Java program?

Tags: java, graalvm

I built the GraalVM JVM code from the project repository ([GraalVM](https://github.com/oracle/graal)), using the [following instructions](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/588).
I think it completed successfully (didn't see any error messages), and it created a new folder graal\vm\mxbuild with what seems to be the compilation product.

My question is, how do I use the compiled JVM to run a java program? usually I would expect some java execution file, but I can't find any.

My goal is to eventually change the JVM code in order to test the behavior of the GC, so if there is a different way to do it with the GraalVM source code I'll appreciate your instructions.

(working on an Ubuntu 18.04 system if it matters..)

Answer (score 1):

The jdk product files can be found in the following folder:
graal/sdk/mxbuild/linux-amd64/GRAALVM_CE_JAVA8/graalvm-ce-java8-20.1.0-dev

It is possible to use the command `mx --env ce graalvm-home` to find the jdk files.

Another thing I found out and maybe can be helpufl for someone in the future, is that it is possible to work and compile only on the jvm project under the Graal project. I order to do so, use the code in [graal-jvmci-8 repository](https://github.com/graalvm/graal-jvmci-8).

Comment: note that graal-jvmci-8 repository doesn't contain the GraalVM compiler, so building that you'll get an OpenJDK build without the GraalVM parts.